# How to understand 2 main() functions after using uftrace to profile the C++ program?

Tags: c++

I am trying [uftrace](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace) to profile the following  simple `C++` program:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
        A() {std::cout << "A is created" << std::endl;}
        ~A() {std::cout << "A is destroyed" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
        A a;
        return 0;
}
```

The profile result is like this:

```
# uftrace a.out
A is created
A is destroyed
# DURATION    TID     FUNCTION
   2.026 us [ 4828] | __cxa_atexit();
            [ 4828] | main() {
            [ 4828] |   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0() {
  89.397 us [ 4828] |     std::ios_base::Init::Init();
   0.768 us [ 4828] |     __cxa_atexit();
  93.029 us [ 4828] |   } /* __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 */
  94.425 us [ 4828] | } /* main */
            [ 4828] | main() {
            [ 4828] |   A::A() {
  11.104 us [ 4828] |     std::operator <<();
  10.825 us [ 4828] |     std::basic_ostream::operator <<();
  24.514 us [ 4828] |   } /* A::A */
            [ 4828] |   A::~A() {
   0.978 us [ 4828] |     std::operator <<();
   1.676 us [ 4828] |     std::basic_ostream::operator <<();
   4.819 us [ 4828] |   } /* A::~A */
  31.428 us [ 4828] | } /* main */
   2.095 us [ 4828] | std::ios_base::Init::~Init();
```

What confuses me is there are `2 main()` functions. From the traces, I guess they are related to `iostream` initialization, but even though, I think there should be only `1 main()` entry for every executable file. How to interpret it?

Comment: There's an internal `main` function used as the real entrypoint to the program, used for initializing global objects. Then it calls the user-defined `main` function.

Comment: @Barmar: "Then it calls the user-defined `main` function", so the second `main` function should be displayed in the first `main` function, is it right?

Comment: It looks like there's some unnamed runtime code that calls both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uftrace` used to remove some prefix in symbol demangler but it may confuse some users so I submitted a patch to keep it and it's merged now - 
https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace/pull/87

So if you update `uftrace` to the current master.  You will see the first `main()` is now `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main()`.

Thanks for your feedback!